# What is the difference between the "bringen" and "mitbringen"?

Tags: word-usage

As I check it up in the dictionary, both carry the meaning of "bring". Is there any difference between the two words? Or they can just replace each other under any circumstance?

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference.

**Example:**

Maria and Robert are sitting at the table, eating. There is no salt on the table, but Maria wants some. She asks Robert, to go into the kitchen and bring some salt:

> *Ger:* Robert, kannst du bitte in die Küche gehen, und mir das Salz **bringen**?
>   *Eng:* Robert, please can you go to the kitchen and bring some salt?

Here, in this example you can not use »*mitbringen*«. Only »*bringen*« is possible here.

---

**mitbringen**
You can use »*mitbringen*« only if the person, who brings something, was already there where they come from. So they come anyway, and, as a side-effect, they also bring something.

The prefix *mit-* has always the meaning of *co-*, i.e. in addition to something else. So it's some kind of "*co*bringing". The person is comming anyway, and co-brings something. So, bringing is in addition to coming.

---

**bringen**
If somebody is going to another place for the only purpose to bring something from there, then it is just »*bringen*«. This person is not coming from there anyway, so *bringing* is not done in addition to something else. So it's not *co-bringing*, but just *bringing*.

Answer (score 2):

In a command for an animal, e. g. dog or elephant, *mitbringen* cannot be used seriously, but *bringen*.

> Bring [mir den] Stock!
>   *(Bring [me the] stick!)*
>   Bring den Baumstamm nach Bombay!
>   *(Carry the tree-trunk to Bombay!)*

This is a special nogo case for *mitbringen*. In general *bringen* means

> - transporting from location A to location B **OR**
> - transporting from location A to one or more persons (or animals)

whereas *mitbringen* usually means

> - transporting from location A to one or more persons (or animals)

Sample with *mitbringen*:

> Die Löwin bringt ihren Jungen Beute mit.
>   *(The lioness brings prey with her for her babies.)*

Need another sample with *bringen*? Omit *mit*!